# Html5 LocalStorage and window.open

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, window.open

So i have this page that contains a button that opens a pop up window:

```
<a onClick="javascript:window.open('{{ path('ChoixSecteur')}}','Choix Secteurs','scroll=yes, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, width=400,height=500')" href="" title="" class="sideB bLightBlue">Ajouter Secteurs</a>
```

in the page that gets oppened i have a form containing a checktree:

```
    <form action="javascript:RecupererSecteurs()" >
    <h1>Secteurs</h1>
    <div id="tree_div" >
        <ul class="tree" id="tree_ul">
           //Check tree Dynamically generated
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Valider</button>
    </form>
```

As for the function `RecupererSecteurs()` it goes like this:

```
function RecupererSecteurs()
{
    i=0;
    localStorage.clear();
    $('ul.tree').find('div.checked').each(function(){
        i++;
        li=$(this).parent('li');
        localStorage.setItem(i,li.find('input:first').val());
    });
   // window.close();
   localStorage.setItem('number',i);
}
```

Now when i submit the form the local storage contains exactely what i want. I close the pop up window and i look for the local storage of the main page i find it empty. Although the two pages are from the same domain.

The URL of the main page : `http://192.168.0.215/Asicx_Merch/web/CreateUserCom/vide/vide/vide`

The URL of the pop up window:

```
http://192.168.0.215/Asicx_Merch/web/ChoixSecteur
```

Is there something that i missed ?! Thanks in advance.
PS: I'm using symfony2.

Comment: You'll probably find you need to refresh your parent page to pull in the new values. The only thing I can suggest is to send back the list of selected values via the `window.opener` or parent of your child window. i.e. `window.opener.choiceSelected(arrayOfSelectedChoices);` and on your parent page, you'd have a function called `choiceSelected` which receives the list and does something with them?